# PHP/MYSQL/MVC how to get current logged on user name

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I'm new to PHP MVC and really am beginning to understand the concept. I have a problem displaying the current user name in a textbox.

Please check my code below:

```
<?php
//require_once (Path::controllerClassPath(). "Summarycontroller.php");
require_once (Path::controllerClassPath(). "CalendarController.php");

//$summary = new SummaryController($this->sessionHandler->getUserId());
$calendar = new CalendarController($this->sessionHandler);

$userId = $this->sessionHandler->getUserId();
?>

<div id="fileleaverequestholiday">
<?php 
echo '<form name="fileleaverequestholidayform" id="fileleaverequestholidayform" action="" method="post">';
echo '<fieldset class="fileleavetables"><legend>Request Leave</legend>';
echo '<table id="fileleaverequesttable">';
echo '<tr>';
//echo '<td class="fileleavetd">Name:</td><td class="fileleavetd"><input id="fileleaveemployeename" type="text" name="fileleaveemployeename"/></td>';
echo '<td class="fileleavetd">Name:</td><td class="fileleavetd"><input id="fileleaveemployeename" type="text" name="fileleaveemployeename" value="'.$retval.'" /> </td>'; ?>
```

I've commented out this fragment of code:

```
    $userId = $this->sessionHandler->getUsername();

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(! $conn )
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT employee_name FROM employee WHERE employee_username = $userId" ;

    mysql_select_db('test');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    print($retval);
    if(! $retval )
    {
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

UPDATED:

```
<div id="fileleaveinsertholiday">
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['fileleaveemployeename'], 
            $_POST['leavetype'], 
            $_POST['filerequestreason'],
            $_POST['filerequeststartdate'])){

if(isset($_POST['filerequestenddate'])){
    if($_POST['filerequestenddate'] > $_POST['filerequeststartdate']){
        $result = $calendar->manageFileHoliday(
                        $_POST['fileleaveemployeename'], 
                        $_POST['leavetype'], 
                        $_POST['filerequestreason'],
                        $_POST['filerequeststartdate'], 
                        '1',
                        $_POST['filerequestenddate']
                     );
        if($result == Status::INSERT_SUCCESS){
            echo '<b>Entry for '.$_POST['fileleaveemployeename'].' from '.$_POST['filerequeststartdate'].' to '.$_POST['filerequestenddate'].' submitted.</b>';         
        }
        else{
            echo '<b>Entry was not submitted. No such name exists in the list.</b>';
        }            
    }
    else{
        echo '<b>Entry was not submitted. Invalid Date Range.</b>';
    }
}
else{
        $result = $calendar->manageFileHoliday(
            $_POST['fileleaveemployeename'], 
            $_POST['leavetype'], 
            $_POST['filerequestreason'],
            $_POST['filerequeststartdate'],
            $_POST['requestduration']
         );
        if($result == Status::INSERT_SUCCESS){
            echo '<b>Entry for '.$_POST['fileleaveemployeename'].' on '.$_POST['filerequeststartdate'].' submitted.</b>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<b>Entry was not submitted. No such name exists in the list.</b>';
        }   
}   
}
?>
</div>
```

Because when I added this, my page is not displaying correctly. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried printing `$retval`? use `print_r` to print it. If so what result is it printing?

Comment: @ganeshrj where will I put print_r? Sorry I'm newbie

Comment: `    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );``print_r($retval)`

Comment: hello it's displaying Resource id #40 not the name?

Comment: `print_r` does not print the record details but the number of rows generated by the query. Then i think you have problem with the query . try assigning your session username to a php variable and then
`$sql = "SELECT employee_name FROM employee ".
        "WHERE employee_id = $phpvar" ;`

Comment: @ganeshrj hello I've updated my post, please check it. I tried what you said, but it still displaying resource id#40

Comment: and displaying this; Could not update data: Unknown column 'malsabio' in 'where clause'

Comment: $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($retval ); and print the row

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes I think abhi has the answer

Comment: I tried what abhi said, php throws this Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: @bEtTy Barnes Can you try run that query in db directly and tell me the result

Comment: Lot of nested `if`s, lot of nested troubles. You should be refactoring your code to a smoother flow.

Comment: MVC is **not** an acronym for "My Very Code".

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code..

```
mysql_select_db('test', $conn)

$retval = mysql_query( $sql);
```

instead of

```
mysql_select_db('test');

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```

Comment: syntax error in @ $retval = mysql_query( $sql);

Comment: Can you share the error for our reference...

Comment: I'm sorry because I just copied and pasted ur code, it's missing ';' in mysql_select_db('test', $conn)

Comment: Now it's displaying the correct logged in user, Array ( [employee_name] => Mary Lourdes Sabio ) but this is on my main page not on the file leave page that I'm talking about

Comment: k..:) Can You find your desire result now..

Comment: I tried it on my file leave page, it's just displaying Array ?

Comment: now return this array to the page you desire. Or if you are using mvc programming framework. return from the controller to the view. display the result in  the view what you want

Comment: try to print $array['employee_name '];

Comment: Means After... $retval = mysql_query( $sql); write $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($retval ); and print_r($row['employee_name ']);

Comment: @abhi, FYI, i have to display the name in a textbox, so I tried: echo '<td class="fileleavetd">Name:</td><td class="fileleavetd"><input id="fileleaveemployeename" type="text" name="fileleaveemployeename" 
value="'.$row.'" /> </td>';

Comment: @bEtTy Barnes try this...<td class="fileleavetd">Name:</td>
<td class="fileleavetd">
 <input id="fileleaveemployeename" type="text" name="fileleaveemployeename" value="<?php echo $row['employee_name '];?>" /> 
</td>

Comment: @bEtTy Barnes cool..:) continue with your work

Comment: @abhi hey I've got a new problem :( it's just displaying but whenever I try to save it, php throws an error :(

Comment: can you share that php error and your insertion code...

Comment: @abhi I've added the code^^

Comment: @bEtTy Barnes please share the php error you are getting and please show your sql query for insertion.. it is very difficult to guess from here

Comment: @abhi this is displaying: echo '<b>Entry was not submitted. No such name exists in the list.</b>'; I'm sorry it's not a php error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21268/discussion-between-abhi-and-betty-barnes)

Comment: @Abhi can you please remove our discussion in chat? For privacy issues. Thanks. I hope this message gets to you.